# rails split response from nokogiri scrape

Tags: ruby-on-rails

So i have this method:

```
doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open(ticketweb_url))
#  Constructing an array of hash
response_hash = doc.css(".ticket-price").map{ |t| {seatname: t.text} }

respond_to do |format|
   format.json  { render :json => response_hash }
end
```

Now the issue i'm having is that its returned like this:

```
  {
    "seatname": "\n\t                Text 1\n\t                \t                    Text 2\n\t                \t                \t                    Text 3\n\t                \t            "
  }
```

When really i'd prefer to have it returned like this

```
{
  "Seatname" {
              "Item 1" : "Text 1"
              "Item 2" : "Text 2"
              "Item 3" : "Text 3"
             }
}
```

Now the element this is in is ticket-price as you can see, However they all have sub elements which are:

```
.h4
.price
.fees
```

If this is any help let me know

Sam